# Understanding Arzela-Ascoli theorem edition 2.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis

This is a question related to the post

[How to understand Arzela-Ascoli theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129606/how-to-understand-arzela-ascoli-theorem)

In that post the notion of bounded as a set is explained in a bit more detail and the requirements of Arzela-Ascoli theorem delved into as well. Recalling the definition of uniformly bounded, we have

A set $M \subseteq C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is uniformly bounded if there exists $L > 0$ such that for all $f \in M$ if we have $sum_{x \in X} |f(x)| \le L$.

In the answer to the post the author @levap prefaces it saying,

"The conditions of Arzela-Ascoli are "uniformly bounded" and "equicontinuous" and not "each function is bounded" and "each function is uniformly continuous". The prefixes "uniformly" and "equi" suggest that those are conditions that are relevant for a set $M$ of functions and cannot be checked for each function $f \in M$ separately."

I thought that the set $M$ has to satisfy this fact that there exists a single constant $L$ that bounds all the functions in the set. In the comments to clarify @levap gives a wonderful example $M = \{nx | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. He again reiterates his preface of not being able to check for each individual function.

This is contrarian to my understanding. I was under the impression that there has to be a single constant that bounds all these functions and does so individually. So in my opinion the example that the author of the answer gave did not and does not satisfy the requirement of uniform boundedness. On the other hand, is the author saying we can do with a weaker condition than the stronger uniform boundedness condition that I have in mind?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, on a compact set X, "equi-continuous" & "family of function evaluated at x being bounded, for each particular x (so the bound could depend on x)" implies uniformly bound. I hope this is where you are confused. I will write a proper response in a bit.

Comment: @fourofour_un thank you, I will wait for your response. The confusion is indeed in the understanding of the notion of what uniformly bound means. Typically uniform anything in my mind means there is a single global constant that apples to all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In for Arzela-Ascoli theorem, uniform boundedness and equicontinuous are the conditions required. And your understanding of uniform boundedness is correct, i.e. for set $M\subseteq C(X,\bf{R})$, it's uniformly bounded if $$\exists L>0 \; s.t. \; \sup_{f\in M\\ x
\in X}|f(x)| \leq L  $$

But notice that for ***compact*** X, if your family of functions $M$ is equi-continuous, then $M$ being *point-wise bounded* is sufficient to show uniform boundedness.

**Proof**

For compact $X$, suppose the set $M\subseteq C(X,\bf{R})$ is pointwise bounded, i.e. for each $x\in X$, $$\exists L_x>0 \; s.t. \sup_{f \in M}|f(x)|\leq L_x $$),

**A)** We want to use equi-continuity, to say that the bounds $L_x, L_y$ are close if $x,y$ are close. Consider $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1 \;, \forall f\in M.$$ So by triangular inequality, for $|x-y|<\delta$, $$\forall f\in M, |f(x)|\leq 1+|f(y)|,$$ therefore by taking sup $$L_x=\sup_{f\in M} |f(x)|\leq  1+\sup_{f\in M}|f(y)|=1+L_y$$, i.e. $$|x-y|<\delta \implies L_x\leq 1+L_y$$

**B)** Now consider the open cover $\bigcup_{x\in X} B(x,\delta)$ of X, by compactness we can find finite subcover s.t.$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\delta).$$

We then take $L=\max_{i=1,...,n}L_{x_i}+1$. I claim that this is the bound we seek. Take any $x\in X$, by **(B)** it must lie within one of the open $\delta$-ball  $B(x_i,\delta)$. Since $|x-x_i|<\delta$, by **(A)** we know $$L_x \leq 1+ L_{x_i}\leq L,$$ by choice of L. So we have proved that $$\forall f\in M, \forall x \in X, |f(x)|\leq L$$.

hence M is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Check out *principles of mathematical analysis* by Rudin, Theorem 7.25 (page 158)

Comment: @fouroffour_un Thank you, I am actually looking at Rudin now that you mentioned it. I do not know why I did not think of looking at Baby Rudin.